# Add patch to the background of a bodeplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've a little function in which I create a bodeplot, like this one:

```
function RequirementTest01
  % create a bode plot
  H = tf([1 0.1 7.5],[1 0.12 9 0 0]);
  %bode(H,{0.1,10});
  bodeHandle = bodeplot(H,{0.1,10});
  get(bodeHandle)
end
```

Now I have the coordinates of a polygon, and I want to create a patch that should be inserted in the background of the plot. Something like the following figure:

[image]

How can I insert the patch in the plot?

Comment: They are not consecutive commands. In the script I show the figure, then the user can open a file from a GUI, where I read data for creating a patch, and by clicking a button I must call a callback where I draw the patch. I've incapsulated all in a class with a `showplot` method that I call for showing it, and a `addpatch` method that I call when I want to add patch data.

Comment: use `bode` to calculate Magnitude and Phase. Then use two subplots with semilogx axis and plot each. This way you get total control of all handles and you can access the according handle of the magnitude plot to add the patch.

Comment: Ok I'll try this solution. Thanks for the suggestion.